# Laravel linode deployment 500:server error

Tags: php, laravel, web-deployment

Okay I know I need to be checking logs but I don't know which ones so that will be start.

I made a blog via laravel and I'm trying to host it on linode. Its using Linux Ngnix mysql laravel. Already gave /storage and /bootstrap/cache permissions so I don't think its that. Where should I start?

Comment: go to storage/logs/ directory, and check the log.

Comment: You set up app folder or public as root into nginx?

Comment: i set the /public folder in nginx